# How to load chuncks of data into memory "in advance" to avoid reading from disk?

Tags: python, memory-management, data-generation

I am training a ConvNet (*Keras, python*) on some custom image dataset directly with my laptop's GPU (*GeForce GTX 1050*). While monitoring my GPU during training, I noticed that it was only used at around 10% of its capacity, or even less. Further investigation made me understand that **the training was bottlenecked by accessing the data from my storage disk** (I am using a data generator).

I also noticed that while the disk was used at 100% capacity, my Memory wasn't (around 65% usage). I thaught : **let's load into Memory "in advance" the next batch of data** (or the few next batches) while the GPU is training on the current batch, **and then access the loaded batch diretcly from Memory, avoiding costly disk reads**. I looked for some documentation or code on stack overflow and other platforms without finding anything relevant.

*One temporary solution I found to avoid this disk read bottlenecking was to paste my data on my OS disk, which is an SSD.* It worked pretty well, reducing training time by a factor of 10-15. But as I have limited storage capacity on the SSD disk (100 Gb), this solution won't work when I will go to heavier data (typically, I am using resampled image (64, 64) for now, but I plan on upscaling to (128, 128) or even more).

Bellow the code for my generator, so you can get a better understanding of the situation :

```py
    def generator(self, passes=np.inf):

        # initialize the epoch count
        db = self.db
        epochs = 0

        # keep looping infinitely -- the model will stop once we have
        # reach the desired number of epochs
        while epochs < passes:
            # shuffle dataset_indices for stochasticity
            if self.shuffle == True: np.random.shuffle(self.dataset_indices)
            # loop over the HDF5 dataset_indices
            for i in np.arange(0, self.numImages, self.batchSize):
                X, Y = [], []

                if self.gaussian_test == True:  # TODO : Add gaussian testing
                    for j in self.dataset_indices[i:i + self.batchSize]:
                        y = db[db[self.gen_type + "_indices"][j]]["label"][()]
                        X.append(np.random.normal(loc=y, scale=0.2, size=(1, 64, 64)))
                        Y.append(y)

                else:
                    for j in self.dataset_indices[i:i + self.batchSize]:
                        X.append(db[db[self.gen_type + "_indices"][j]]["array"][()])
                        Y.append(db[db[self.gen_type + "_indices"][j]]["label"][()])

                X = np.array(X)
                Y = np.array(Y)
                Y = to_categorical(Y, num_classes=6)
                # yield a tuple of images and labels
                yield (X, Y)
            # increment the total number of epochs
            epochs += 1
```

I am not sure how to proceed, but I am pretty sure that it should be possible...

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't receive any answer for now, I am sharing my findings for anyone who would be interested by the topic. Actually, the idea I was looking for was to use multi-processing...

**(I) :** After some research, I found that Keras *fit_generator()* allows for such *multi-processing* via the arguments ***use_multiprocessing = True*** and ***workers = n***. But this method has its limits :

- First, your generator ***must be thread safe***. If your generator is inheriting from Keras.utils.Sequence class, it is already thread safe. Else, refer to this [tutorial](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/tip-fit_generator-in-keras-how-to-parallelise-correctly/) where you'll learn how to create a decorator that will make your generator thread safe.
- Second, if you are using a Windows computer, then you can't set ***use_multiprocessing = True*** as it is not implemented. Though, I realized that you can still set ***workers = n > 1*** but then I think your generator won't be thread safe, which is an issue.

**(II) :** As I am using a Windows computer, this didn't work for me. I then found other resources ([TensorFlow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/queue_runner/QueueRunner), [Blog post](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/introduction-tensorflow-queuing/))suggesting to use ***TensorFlow QueueRunner class***. This seems to be the most efficient and robust solution, but you need to user TensorFlow, which can be time consuming if you have to dive into it for the first time. I didn't try this solution yet, as I am expecting to move to AWS cloud in the coming days, hence allowing me to use the first solution.